# Где посмотреть значения кодов child_process.spawn?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я написал простой класс для `child_process.spawn`.

В нём есть:

```
this.#process.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log('~~~~~exit~~~~~~~~', code)
});
this.#process.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log('~~~~~close~~~~~~~~', code)
});
```

Где можно посмотреть список кодов, которые приходят при завершении процесса?

[Здесь где то должно быть, но я не вижу...](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

Дополнение:

[image: коды которые мне приходят]

Comment: Код возвращает вызываемая программа, и список кодов нужно смотреть в документации вызываемой вами программы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё там сложно, т.к. зависит от программы. Единственная конвенция - если возвращается `0`, то всё хорошо.

В случае с Windows, к примеру, можете почитать [эту](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes?redirectedfrom=MSDN) статью.

Про Linux можно почитать в [этом ответе](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254747/124693).

Comment: Спасибо. мне получше надо разобраться будет. У меня из библиотеки два кода только приходит 0 true 1 false. Здесь мне этого хватило что бы перезапускать демона, если он уже запущен. 
В дополнении картинку прикрепил с процессом перезапуска.